# Rails testing actions based on uniqueness of three joined attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

A model has three references, which combined should be unique

```
class Roleshopuser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :role
  
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:shop_id, :role_id] }
end
```

the database has an index defined accordingly:

```
  t.index [:user_id, :shop_id, :role_id], unique: true
```

However when testing the controller create action

```
setup do
  @roleshopuser = roleshopusers(:dummy)
end

test "should create roleshopuser" do
@roleshopusers = Roleshopuser.all
@roleshopusers.each do |rsu|
 puts rsu.role_id
 puts rsu.shop_id
 puts rsu.user_id
 puts "|"
end
assert_difference('Roleshopuser.count') do
  post roleshopusers_url, params: { roleshopuser: { role_id: @roleshopuser.role_id, shop_id: @roleshopuser.shop_id, user_id: @roleshopuser.user_id } }
end
end
```

the fixture has the references set to integers:

```
dummy:
  user_id: 7
  shop_id: 1
  role_id: 1
```

& each reference does have a fixture with the shown ID defined.

The record is not saving:

```
"Roleshopuser.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 8
  Actual: 7
```

Interestingly the output of existing records includes the setup record.

```
830861402
459312771
135138680
|
830861402
459312771
701618302
|
830861402
459312771
590087265
|
830861402
459312771
290770238
|
689480364
459312771
483292939
|
689480364
459312771
1058249888
|
1
1
7
|
```

Thus the validation is kicking in properly.
If I modify the input data to:

```
shop_id: (@roleshopuser.shop_id + 1)
```

This creates the record, as it is now unique relative to the preceeding lot.

I see the source of the problem: the default scaffolding generated test fails by design in this instance as it is considering all the defined fixtures as existing.

So how can the test be reliably written (after all rails could come up with chance IDs for the attributes to be identical - low probability, yes)?

Comment: Its hard for anybody to tell you what you may be missing if we are missing huge chunks of the picture (like say the controller and the actual test setup). You really need to provide a minimal verifiable example for debugging help. And you might want to start with a simple test that just tests the validation on the model layer and then work your way up to the controller. Also don't forget about a DB index.

Comment: You are correct. I went back, retraced steps, found some issues with fixtures, then zeroed in on the problem. QUestion re-cast. I am not even sure I should even bother to test this, as there is the database level validation (and client-side will also impede erroneous entry).